# how to change number of columns and rows showing in R studio notebook dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

When I run my R studio notebook, the dataframe/tables are defaulted to 10 rows. How can I display 20 rows?

As well, if I have many columns, I have to click the "next" button on the top right to see the other columns. How can I display all the columns at the same time? The browser definitely has enough space to view a bigger table, but could this be another possible solution to view all the columns together: shrink the font in each column? If so, how can I do this?

This is different from the "View" function, and because it's a notebook, the visualization of the dataframe is different from a regular R executable in R studio. Instead of the view function, I'm using the head(x,20) function to display the first 20 rows, but the notebook makes me hit the page 2 tab to see the next 10 rows.

Comment: For those interested, I've found some commands that do something similar: specifying `rows.print=20` allowed me to show 20 rows but `cols.print=10` did not display all the columns, the columns still get paged, despite having ample space in the browser window. I'm not sure whether  `paged.print` is able to display all the columns, but a side effect is that it removes all formatting in the tables and makes the aesthetics really poor, so I'm not interested in using it.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've been looking for this for a while.

Comment: `cols.print = 18` worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

For displaying more columns, is it something like this?

````
```{r set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
options(width = 120)
```
````

Comment: Are you asking or giving an answer. BTW the solution of `options(width = 120)` does not increase the columns nor the width.

Answer (score -2):

```
options(repr.matrix.max.cols=50, repr.matrix.max.rows=100)
```