# How to increase number of columns displayed inside R Notebook in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

A possible duplicate of [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489697/how-to-change-number-of-columns-and-rows-showing-in-r-studio-notebook-dataframe?rq=1), adding code/screenshot here to hopefully clarify what the issue is.

When I run a chunk that outputs a data frame, I'm only getting one column per screen. I.e., running

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  select(col1, col2)
```

Produces the image below, where only col1 is displayed, and I have to click the arrow (not shown) to see the other column.

[image]

This seems to happen because col2 is a text field with several hundred characters, and so RStudio decides to give it as much real estate as possible, rather than placing it next to col1 (wasting all that space for the sake of displaying a handful of more characters).

Is it possible to override this setting? If so, can col2's output also be wrapped to screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `flextable` to control the width of columns printed on the screen, but you also have to make sure you don't select too many columns. For example, if `col1` should be thin and `col2` should be wide, do something like this:

```
library(flextable)
df %>% select(col1, col2) %>% regulartable() %>%
    fontsize(size=8,part="all") %>% width(j=c(1:2),width=c(0.4,3))
```

The `j` is `flextable`'s way of referring to columns, and the `width` values are width in inches if you print the table in a doc or PDF.